# a clear example of how to use Google UI Builder and Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have searched everywhere and cannot find a clear example of how to use Googles UI Builder and apps script.  I have no clue what I'm missing.  I think this should be simple :v/  YES, I've read all Googles docs, watched vids etc - several times - there is no combination of GUIB *(Google's UI Builder)* and a callback handler function, that I can find.
***EDIT: there are examples for SpreadSheets - not GSites***

**What I need to do:**
I would like to embed a textbox and button to collect a search phrase from a user, on a Google site page. I have built the very simple UI with a single flowpanel, textbox and button, but can only ever get "Undefined" returned from Logger.log() no matter what I do *(see code below)*.

**A bit of a rant:**
I have been very careful to name, and call by the right names.  I've tried using a formpanel BUT in GUIB, you can only put ONE widget in it?! ...AND a submit button will only go into a formpanel - huh - I can't put my text box in as well!?  *(Why bother with the formpanel then - I don't get that! ...yeah I know about doPost() automatically being called on submit)*. I want the widgets to remain active and not disappear after one use, so maybe formpanel/submitbutton won't work anyway - or isn't the right way to do it?

**Down to business:**
 
At any rate, what I've tried is to put the regular button and text box in a flowpanel with the following code...
***EDIT: I deleted my original content here and reposted this section...***

```
// Google Sites and UIBuilder (GUIB) - kgingeri (Karl)
// - this script is embedded in a GSite page via: Insert -> Apps Script Gadget.
//
// Withing GUIB I have defined:
// - a FlowPanel named 'pnlMain'
// - inside that a textBox named 'tbxQuery' and a button called 'btnSearch'
// - for btnSearch, I have defined (in the Events subsection) a callback function
//   btnSearchHandler (see it below doGet() here.  I expanded the [+] beside that
//   and entered 'tbxQuery'    
//
// the GUIB compnent tree looks like this...
//
//  [-] testGui
//    [-] pnlMain
//          btnSearch
//          tbxQuery
//
// btnSearch Event section looks something like this...
//
// Events
//  On Mouse Clicks
//  [X][btnSearchHandler][-]
//  [tbxQuery         ]<--'
//  [Add Server]
//  ...
//
// So... 
// 1) when the page is opened, the doGet() function is called, showing the defined UI 
// 2) when text is entered into the textBox and the button is clicked
// 3) the data from tbxQuery is **SUPPOSED TO BE** returned as e.parameter.tbxQuery
//    in the function 'btnSearchHandler(e)' **BUT IS NOT**  :v(
//
// (this functionality appears to work in a spreadsheet?! - weird?!)

//
//    [ predefined function --- Google calls on page open ]
//
// ...this works 'as advertised' ;v)
//
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("testGui"));  // ...the title that shows in G/UIBuilder
  return app;
}

//
//    [ callBack for when a button is clicked ]
//
// ...I always get 'Resp: [Undefined]' returned in the View -> Logs menu?!
// ...I also tried to put 'pnlMain' in the Event [+] param, no go :v(
//
function btnSearchHandler(e) {
  var resp = e.parameter.tbxQuery  // ...the data I want in the textBox widget
  Logger.log('Resp: [' + e.parameter.tbxQuery + ']');
  // ...more code to come, once this works!
}
```

I've also tried adding code to manually set handlers etc in doGet(), and not use GUIB Event settings, but to no avail either.

**Conclusion?**
What Gives?  Do I have to hand-code the GUIs and not use GUIB?  I know it's a simple one this time, but if I can get this working I can sure see being much nicer to build other apps with GUIB!  Can anyone give me or point me to a clear example?!

Thanks for reading!

Comment: wow, this is a 'late' accept ! thanks ;-))

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that Serge!! ;v) I just noticed I never did it!!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Class UiApp was deprecated. Nowadays Class HtmlService should be used to create a web app with Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is a shared spreadsheet with an [example of GUI builder](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dHNGY1QwRFBTSl82eFpMekk0TDMzdEE)

when you're in the GUI builder look at the properties of the element you want to trigger a function, at the end of the parameter list there is an 'EVENT' properties where you can add the function name and the callbackElements as well. !

[image: screen capture]

Hoping it's clear enough,
cheers,
Serge

EDIT : if you want to have a look at a more complex example please [open this one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dFZ2ajhKblJxUlBFTU1pdjUtZVdLTWc) (create a copy of it to make it editable) or see it working [here](https://docs.google.com/macros/exec?service=AKfycbyc2SWv6JhDgUpXwF7aAARihIE7WPRmrQf6KIOtfQ), I think you might be convinced that the GUI builder is a really powerfull tool .

Comment: Thanks Serge! 

I certainly **DID NOT NOTICE THE SMALL [+]** below the event property.  I have most definitely tried using the event property --- I could not post my screen shots, or you would have seen it.  

I am working with Sites not Spreadsheets - not sure if that is different?  I assume you put the name of the other widgets you want included in the callback here - i.e. mine would be txtBox?  It still did not work for me, so I will study your ss example more. But thanks again!!

Comment: Serge (or others) still can't make it work.  Serge's example works as expected in a copy of his sheet.  It doesn't with Sites?!
   .    
**I'VE UPDATED MY ORIGINAL POST TO SHOW ALL DEFINITIONS (without screen shots)**

Comment: So I thought I'd set thru any e.parameter values I got back and it turns out they are all values that define the button and click event... (this won't format right in a comment) ...
 / param[clientY] = 61
 / param[clientX] = 94
 / param[eventType] = click
 / param[ctrl] = false
 / param[meta] = false
 / param[source] = btnQuery
 / param[button] = 1
 / param[alt] = false
 / param[screenY] = 549
 / param[screenX] = 426
 / param[y] = 12
 / param[shift] = false
 / param[x] = 85
 ...so little wonder I get back 'Undefined'!!  So how do I get the data I want?!

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot of my answer the parameter that must be set after the '+' is the NAME of the text box(or a parent panel), the returned values will then be available as e.parameter.itemname.

Comment: I do insist that it should be the NAME of the textbox, not its ID , and this should be set in the right panel in the 'INPUT FIELDS' subframe. btw the reservation GUI that I showed as complex example is running on a site without any change compared to the spreadsheet version.

Comment: Looking at your code you could use pnlMain as callbackelement as well but it should work with tbxQuery as long as their NAME parameters are defined correctly.

Comment: "NAME" was it - something I had looked for but also missed (in Input Fields?!)  **---THANKS Serge---**  I am posting the answer!

Comment: It only works for me when I use the ID value, not the Name value.

Comment: could you describe your usecase ? maybe it would be better to open a new thread, this is becoming quite a long comment serie ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Many thanks to Serge Insas!!**

The answer is as shown below - I had missed two things:

1. the small [+] beside the **On Mouse Click** server handler - to add
   a parameter to return
2. the **Name** is what is used NOT ID - set in
   **Input Fields** section of tbxQuery

> (NOTE: non-data elements don't have names - so fplMain has only an ID, but still works)

So, here is the resulting code, and comments describing GUIB settings:

```
// Google Sites and UIBuilder (GUIB) - kgingeri (Karl)
// - this script is embedded in a GSite page via: Insert -> Apps Script Gadget.
//
// Withing GUIB I have defined:
// - a FlowPanel named 'fplMain'
// - inside that, a textBox named 'tbxQuery' (see Input Fields section - this in NOT ID)
//   and a button called 'btnSearch'
// - for btnSearch, I have defined (in the Events subsection) a callback function
//   btnSearchHandler (see it below doGet() here).  I expanded the [+] beside that,
//   and entered "fplMain" as the return param (it will return all data elements)   
//
// the GUIB compnent tree looks like this...
//
//  [-] SearchGui
//    [-] fplMain
//          btnSearch
//          tbxQuery
//
// "tbxQuery" Input Fields param, "Name"... **THIS MUST BE SET!
//
// Input Fields
//  ...
//  Name
//  [tbxQuery     ]
//
// "btnSearch" Event section looks like this...
//
// Events
//  On Mouse Clicks
//  [X][btnSearchHandler][-]
//  [fplMain          ]<--'
//  [Add Server]
//  ...
//
// So... 
// 1) when the page is opened, the doGet() function is called, showing the defined UI 
// 2) when text is entered into the textBox and the button is clicked
// 3) the data from tbxQuery is returned as e.parameter.tbxQuery (as would be any other
//    params under the flow panel "fplMain") in the function 'btnSearchHandler(e)'

//
//    [ predefined function --- Google calls on page open ]
//
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("SearchGUI"));  // ...the title you choose in G/UIBuilder
  return app;
}

//
//    [ callBack for when a button is clicked ]
//
function btnSearchHandler(e) {
  var resp = e.parameter.tbxQuery  // ...the data in the textBox widget
  Logger.log('Resp: [' + e.parameter.tbxQuery + ']');
  //
  // ...more code goes here, to do something with the returned data
  //
}
```